# Get value from JSONEncode PHP and show it into listview

Tags: php, android, json

Is there any actual and simple tutorial for getting value from PHP and store it into list view ?

So this is the activity flow :

```
1. Input number in textview
2. Submit via button and send the value from textview into website
3. The website give the result in json_encode form.
4. Set the value from JSON into listview or multiline text maybe.
```

This is the PHP code :

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$query_search1 = "SELECT `schedule`.`kode_schedule` ,`schedule`.`kode_matkul` ,`matakuliah`.`title` ,`schedule`.`ruang` ,`kelas`.`latitude` ,`kelas`.`longitude` ,`kelas`.`lantai` ,`schedule`.`hari`,`schedule`.`jam` FROM schedule LEFT JOIN `u466318196_track`.`matakuliah` ON `schedule`.`kode_matkul` = `matakuliah`.`kode_matkul` LEFT JOIN `u466318196_track`.`kelas` ON `schedule`.`ruang` = `kelas`.`ruang` WHERE(( kode_schedule = '".$username."'))";
$query_exec1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query_search1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while ($data2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_exec1))
{
 $response['length'][] = $data2;
}

print json_encode($response);
```

This is the result from PHP :

```
{
"length":
[
  {
      "kode_schedule":"sch0001",
      "kode_matkul":"TIB01",
      "title":"Basis Data",
      "ruang":"501",
      "latitude":"-6.18861653446272",
      "longitude":"106.801122526546",
      "lantai":"5",
      "hari":"Selasa",
      "jam":"17:45:00"
  },          
  {
      "kode_schedule":"sch0001",
      "kode_matkul":"TIB02",
      "title":"Pemrograman Berorientasi Objek",
      "ruang":"LABB",
      "latitude":"-6.18864706134991",
      "longitude":"106.801161122636",
      "lantai":"5",
      "hari":"Selasa",
      "jam":"19:30:00"
   }
]
}
```

I'm still newbie about android. Please give me some fully tutorial or code.

Best regards.

**EDIT :**

I have done many research and still cannot succeed. So it's not like i haven't doing anything.

This is my code :

```
public void login()
{
    try
    {
        httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpPost= new HttpPost("http://studentstracking.hol.es/installation.php");
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", txtNim.getText().toString().trim()));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        response=httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        final String response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);
        final JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
        String kode_matkul;
        String title;
        String ruang;
        String lantai;
        String hari;
        int jam;
        Double latitude,longitude;
        ListAdapter setListAdapter;
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
        ArrayList items = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i < array.length() ; i++) {
            JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
            kode_matkul = row.getString("kode_matkul");
            title = row.getString("title");
            ruang = row.getString("ruang");
            latitude = row.getDouble("latitude");
            longitude = row.getDouble("longitude");
            lantai = row.getString("lantai");
            hari = row.getString("hari");
            jam = row.getInt("jam");
            items.add(kode_matkul);
            items.add(title);
            items.add(ruang);
            items.add(latitude);
            items.add(longitude);
            items.add(lantai);
            items.add(hari);
            items.add(jam);
        }
        ArrayAdapter mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_installation,R.id.listView2);
        listView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(Installation.this, "Welcome : " + array , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Google for ListView Android tutorial, try to write something, return if you have an problem. Steps to build: Build textview with button, send to server with http client (loopj lib for ex.), take response, parse it (Gson lib fo ex.), set this data to listview with an custom adapter.

Comment: You need to work on your android knowledge more. Like Alexander said, try googling or try referring to Android API. For example here's what you need for a server side request. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html

Comment: If it is easy like you have been told, i will not ask in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Here's some tips for you,

**Step 1 :** Create a JSON parser class for handling the network operations,

```
public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }       
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

**Step 2 :** From your activity call the PHP API using an AsyncTask,

```
    class GetLength extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", txtNim.getText().toString()));
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://studentstracking.hol.es/installation.php", "POST", params);
                JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("length");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    kode_matkul = row.getString("kode_matkul");
                    title = row.getString("title");
                    ruang = row.getString("ruang");
                    latitude = row.getDouble("latitude");
                    longitude = row.getDouble("longitude");
                    lantai = row.getString("lantai");
                    hari = row.getString("hari");
                    jam = row.getInt("jam");
                    items.add(kode_matkul);
                    items.add(title);
                    items.add(ruang);
                    items.add(latitude);
                    items.add(longitude);
                    items.add(lantai);
                    items.add(hari);
                    items.add(jam);
                }
            }
            );

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            // set your list adapter here 
        }
    }
```

Comment: it looks great. So where do i must put both of the class ? In the same activity or new class ?

Comment: You can put both classes in the same activity, but I suggest you to use the JSONParser class separately and not inside a activity class.

Comment: So how to call GetLength class ? is it just run automatically or how ?

Comment: From your activity, new GetLength().execute();

Comment: And how to call the jsonParser in JSONParser into GetLength ? Sorry for troubling you

Comment: JSONParser takes 3 parameters, 1. url. 2. method 3. params which can be used as JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest("http://studentstracking.hol.es/installation.php", "POST", params); and already written inside the doInBackground task of getLength()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83715/discussion-between-leonard-febrianto-and-prokash-sarkar).